# Check if date is weekend - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Can anyone please advise how to check if a date is weekend in AngularJS. I've seen a lot of examples in JS but need one in Angular.

```
function weekendChecker(date) {
   if (date.getDay() == 6 || date.getDay() == 0) {
       return true;
    }
   return false;
}
```

And then I use it like so

```
<span ng-if="weekendChecker(cart[0].date)" class="meta-content" ng-bind="(data.weekendot | limitTo:5) + ' - ' + (data.weekendct | limitTo: 5)"></span>
<span ng-if="!weekendChecker(cart[0].date)" class="meta-content" ng-bind="(data.weekdayot | limitTo:5) + ' - ' + (data.weekdayct | limitTo: 5)"></span>
```

Comment: What is `cart[0].date`? Is it a date object?

Comment: `Can anyone confirm if my code below is correct please.` - surely you're the only person who can answer that! Does it work, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.dates = [new Date(2015, 11, 31), new Date(2016, 0, 3)];
    $scope.isWeekend = function (date) {
        return (date.getDay() === 6) || (date.getDay() === 0);
    };
});
```

```css
.weekend {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="date in dates">
      <span ng-show="isWeekend(date)" class="weekend">
        Weekend: {{date|date:'d MMMM yy'}}
      </span>
      <span ng-hide="isWeekend(date)">
        Weekday: {{date|date:'d MMMM yy'}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```